# In AutoDesk Forge how to spin a component by using C# html coding

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

Can you please explain c# html code for spinning a component (node) in Autodesk forge .

I am using dot net core 2.2

Comment: A bit more clarification on what exactly you are looking for might help best. what code? spinning a model or a part of the model? Anything that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Transformation can be done in pure JavaScript with the THREE.js library (a WebGL based graphics API, learn more for your purpose [here](https://discoverthreejs.com/book/1-first-steps/6-shapes-transformations/)) so .NET is out of the equation for your purpose. See sample code below (full sample [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/MyForgeBlogs/tree/22c59a93a17d500f8fb28672c9d7c63776c0e20e/02.ViewerObjectRotation)):

```
let dbid = viewer.getSelection(); //make sure you point to the root node of target component

let tree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree; //obtain model object tree

tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (frag) {
    var fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, frag);
    fragProxy.getAnimTransform();
    fragProxy.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(
                                    new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), 
                                    -Math.PI/2); //spin the component by 90 degrees
    fragProxy.updateAnimTransform(); //notify fragment proxy to perform animation
});

viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true); //notify Viewer to update scene
```

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics) for details on how to transform components.

Also see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/02/behind-the-scene-of-view-of-autodesk-view-and-data-fragment.html) for more about [dbid](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/index.html#model-object-tree) and fragments.